# Required commandline options in Python using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following scenario for command line argument. If there is a particular option then there should be some other required options. For example if there is -- create then there should be --name. Also if there is --remove then there should be --id. Is it possible to implement this scenario with argparse? or someother thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with [subcommands](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) as long as you don't mind `create` and `remove` not being preceded with hyphens.  This may make sense anyway, since those verbs are often used as actions rather than options.

Comment: @bonzi: Cheers.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it does end up being the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Optional is implicit, required must be specified:

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#required

That said, there doesn't appear to be a built-in mechanism for argument "dependencies", as I think you would like to implement.  This would be a requirement for your application.